# Display results of multi join query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL query which displays 2 rows retrieved but when I echo the field `name` nothing is retrieved. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
FROM tag_map
LEFT JOIN tags2 ON tags2.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id
LEFT JOIN video ON video.vid_id = tag_map.vid_id
WHERE tag_map.vid_id=?';
$stmt_tags = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt_tags->execute(array($vid_id));
echo $tag_count=$stmt_tags->rowCount(); //shows 2
$tags = array();
while ($row = $stmt_tags->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

**EDIT:** Var_dump using suggested query

```
SELECT tag_map.*, tags2.name AS tag_name
FROM tag_map
LEFT JOIN tags2 ON tags2.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id
LEFT JOIN video ON video.vid_id = tag_map.vid_id
WHERE tag_map.vid_id=?


array(4) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1234" ["vid_id"]=> string(32) "8364a8e463052e215a5dc174c92a2f18" ["tag_id"]=> string(32) "4c71a73d001dd9c09c7d9d95907bf1fe" ["tag_name"]=> NULL } array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "123" ["vid_id"]=> string(32) "8364a8e463052e215a5dc174c92a2f18" ["tag_id"]=> string(32) "57bb5dd83dc84e7115387886e328b04b" ["tag_name"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: The only way this works: "echo $row['name'];" is if the field names are literally named 'name'. Is that the case? I kind of doubt it. Do this to see what's really in row: var_dump($row);

Comment: OMG, a PHP developer using PDO. There's hope after all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be specific in your `SELECT` clause, particularly when joining other tables.

For example

```
SELECT tag_map.vid_id, tag_map.name, tags2.name AS tag_name
```

Notice how I've used an alias for `tags2.name` to avoid a column name conflict with `tag_map.name`.

I'm only guessing here but I'd say you have a `name` column in one of your left-joined tables that's overriding `tag_map.name`.

### Update

In light of the extra information, I'd have to say it's solely due to your left-joins. The records where `tags2.name` is showing NULL simply do not have related fields in `tag_map` for the `vid_id` in question.

If you only want to show records where there is a relation between `tag_map` and `tags2`, use `INNER JOIN`

Demo here - http://sqlize.com/UL1M80DT0c

Comment: I took your advice and used var_dump and for some reason the column name came up as null... but the vid_id and tag_id are correct. That must mean the tags2 where name is stored is not being joined properly...

Comment: @Scarface wasn't my advice :/

Comment: You are awesome PHIL!!! That demo was really cool as well. Just like jfiddle but for SQL. Cheers buddy!

Answer (score 2):

Be more explicit about the columns and tables in your `SELECT` list:

```
$sql = "SELECT tag_map.*, tags2.*, video.* 
FROM tag_map
LEFT JOIN tags2 ON tags2.tag_id = tag_map.tag_id
LEFT JOIN video ON video.vid_id = tag_map.vid_id
WHERE tag_map.vid_id=?";
```

If you don't need all columns from all tables, remove the tables you don't need.  Even better is to explicitly name *only* the columns you need, as in:

```
SELECT 
  tag_map.name,
  tag_map.id,
  ...
  ...
  video.length
FROM ...etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure there's a column called `name`? Array keys are cases sensitive, so if it's `Name` then you need that.

Also, try a `var_dump($row)` to see what all is there.